# User Defaults not saving my array when my app gets reopen

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I am quite new to Swift, but I have been using User Defaults for a while now and never had any issue like this. I am using an alert with a textfield that request a clients name so I can append to my clientArray.

My issue is that the User Defaults reset after every app launch.

The code I have after the user saves the name is:

```
self.clientArray.append(clientName.text!)
self.defaults.setValue(clientArray, forKey: "Clients")
print(clientArray)
```

This works well and indeed every time I add a new name, I see on the console my array will all the client names on it with no issue, however, anytime I close my app, my array is completely empty and so is my User Defaults value, completely erasing the previous saved client names.

I have also tried to use it like this:

```
self.clientArray.append(clientName.text!)
self.defaults.set(clientArray, forKey: "Clients")
print(clientArray)
```

Just in case that it would behave differently, but it has not.

Could anyone point me what I am missing or point me the right direction? Other than this my app is running flawlessly.

Thank you in advance.

Update as requested:

The way I am reading the array is:

```
let clientArrayResult = self.defaults.array(forKey: "Clients")
print(\(clientArrayResult))
```

Comment: Never use `setValue` with UserDefaults. Your 2nd example is the correct way to save the array. But your question doesn't show how you read the array. Update your question with relevant code showing where and how you load the array from UserDefaults. Also note that you should not be using UserDefaults to save app data. That's not what UserDefaults is for.

Comment: " I close my app, my array is completely empty and so is my User Defaults value" How do you know these two are empty at the point you close the app?

Comment: Thank you for both your comments. My mistake, I should have added the final part, I am truly sorry!

I am running a print command on my array on User Defaults. Also, I thought about using User Defaults for this because the array won't be too long and I need to save this data locally for when it is being used offline. I do not intend to launch the app, is mostly for my company usage.

P.S.: I am running the print command on my ViewDidLoad to make sure the array was saved, hence how I found out about the issue itself.

Comment: Also, if there is any other way I can save a small array on device that would work better than using my User Default, please let me know, I would be very appreciative of it.

Comment: Why are you not using UserDefault.standard ?

Comment: I am, I simply have a variable that shortens UserDefaults.standard, hence why I am using defaults only.

Comment: Use Core Data. While there is a bit of a learning curve, it isn't that hard and it is much better than trying to use user defaults for a purpose for which it wasn't intended.

Comment: Since you don't show what `clientArray` is, my guess is that it could be an array of Strings. In that case, have you tried: 
`let clientArrayResult = UserDefault.standard.array(forKey: "Clients") as? [String] ?? []`.

Comment: I did not try that, will do first thing tomorrow morning! Also, I’ll have a look into Core Data, thank you.

Comment: So I figured it out. The code itself was fine, my issue was that I forgot to write code to check if there was previously saved user defaults saved strings, so my code was just initializing from an empty array.